# File coverage tab is always loading and never shows coverage files when using OpenCover plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, code-coverage, opencover

###### Background

I'm using OpenCover 4.7.1221 to run vstest.console.exe in a Jenkins pipeline via bat script in a steps block to generate a coverage.xml file. Then, I'm running the Code Coverage API plugin with the OpenCover plugin adapter (```publishCoverage adapters: [opencoverAdapter```) to generate the code coverage from the coverage.xml file. My setup is very similar to the setup used in the following [this blog post][1].

When the job is complete, a Coverage Report link displays on the menu. When I click the Coverage Report link, there is a Coverage Overview chart and a Coverage Trend chart. Below the two charts, there's a Coverage Details section that has two tabs. The default selected tab is File Coverage and the other tab is Package Overview.

If I click Package Overview, a code coverage heat map displays with the heading, "OpenCover coverage: coverage.xml". However, when I click the File Coverage tab, it displays a DataTables.net table that just says, "Loading - please wait ...". This table never changes and never shows any files or source code as I'm guessing it's supposed to.

[image: Jenkins OpenCover Plugin - File Coverage Tab]

I have searched for answers and found nothing. I searched images and found nothing. Most articles, forum posts, or blogs use ReportGenerator.exe to create an HTML report and import that into Jenkins, and I have done that successfully, but I'm curious why nothing ever loads on the File Coverage tab.

###### Question

Does this not work and is that why I'm only seeing the ReportGenerator.exe output in my searches? I'm primarily interested in whether or not this ever works so I can decide whether to continue spending time on it. If it does work and someone has a working example, that would be great, too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The same issue occurs with llvm-cov, so it appears that the plugin is currently broken.  With an older version of the plugin, the data was all visible.